# ошибка Could not get unknown property 'API_KEY' for BuildType_Decorated

Tags: android-studio

код ошибки:

Could not get unknown property 'API_KEY' for BuildType_Decorated{name=debug, debuggable=true, testCoverageEnabled=false, jniDebuggable=false, pseudoLocalesEnabled=false, renderscriptDebuggable=false, renderscriptOptimLevel=3, minifyEnabled=false, zipAlignEnabled=true, signingConfig=SigningConfig_Decorated{name=debug, storeFile=C:\Users\voiger.android\debug.keystore, storePassword=android, keyAlias=AndroidDebugKey, keyPassword=android, storeType=jks, v1SigningEnabled=true, v2SigningEnabled=true}, embedMicroApp=false, mBuildConfigFields={API_KEY=com.android.builder.internal.ClassFieldImpl@fe07593c}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.

при запуске падает ошибка исправить сам не могу(я новичок,и криворукий) пытался сам поискать решение но не нашёл

вот самое приложение: https://github.com/RobertBeaudenon/SOEN390-CampusGuideMap
не моё приложение

Comment: Когда возникает такая ошибка? Отформатируйте её

Comment: https://github.com/RobertBeaudenon/SOEN390-CampusGuideMap
при запуске падает ошибка 
исправить сам не могу(я новичок,и криворукий)
пытался сам поискать решение но не нашёл

Comment: Всё для решения вопроса должно быть в вопросе, а не по ссылкам. Используйте кнопку править